# laravel withcount changes relationship result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to count relationship using a scope to count a filtered part of the relationship

```
Parent::
withWhereHas('children')
->withCount(['children', function (Builder $builder) {
  $builder->where('status', 1);
}])
->get()
```

The Parent has 36 Children, 6 of them are status = 1 and the variable added is right, i retrieve childens_count = 6.

But i only retrieve the 6 children in the relationship array, whereas i didn't scoped the withWhereHas, so i guess i'm missing something. Is the withCount having any side effect on the whole request ? Didn't see this in the doc.

Here are the relationships in models :

```
// Programme Model
public function childrens(): HasMany
{
  return $this->hasMany(Children::class);
}

// Children Model
public function parent(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
}
```

Any suggestion appreciated !

Comment: Thanks for reply ! I want the 36 items in the list, i don't want to scope the among of results, just the withCount

Comment: Are you sure that the comment in the docs doesn't explain your problem? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence It looks to me that it is exactly doing what it is intended to do...  `For example, you may wish to only retrieve User models that have child Post models matching a given query condition while also eager loading the matching posts`

Comment: You can do `DB::enableQueryLog(); /* run query here */ dd(DB::getQueryLog());` to see what the exact queries are. I've tried it on one of my 1 to many relationships and it seems to work as expected so maybe there's some sort of global scope being applied here

Comment: Can you add the query you mention , the one without scope withWhereHas? Also share how do you set this `children` relationship inside Parent model. Thanks

Comment: @win i said the withWhereHas has no scope, there is always a withWhereHas condition. I don't filter the withWhereHas, but when combined with the withCount filtered, it returns a filtered query with the withCount condition

Comment: I apologize, a bit new in laravel 9 , and withWhereHas() , should it not contain 2 parameters ? like `->withWhereHas('children', fn ($q) => $q->where('condition', 'value'))`

Comment: @win The closure is not mandatory, it stands for with('children') where('children') count > 0. Here i don't want to filter this relationship. I want the 36 results. When i don't put the withCount i get them all. But adding the withCount, it returns me only the 6 results from the withCount condition

Comment: can you please clarify , 36 children out of single parent OR from all parents .. because ->get() stands for return all parents , also try removing the condition inside withCount should help remedy problem returning 6 instead of 36

Comment: Yes, removing the condition inside withCount does resolve the problem, it retrieve the 36 items. But it counts also 36. And i want it to count only the children with status 1

Comment: I have run my test for returning single Parent and `count($parent->children)` has different result compare to `$parent->children_count` (with condition status == 1) , just like in your case 36 and 6 . Can you show your children relationship inside Parent model ?

Comment: @win i edited my post with the defined relationships

Comment: thanks, i have also updated my answer with the last part the query + how to count all children and get counted children with condition is active , the difference is `Parent::query()->..` it seems adding query will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From how I understand your question, this is the query that you need to use to retrieve all of the 36 children

```
$parents = Parent::with('children')->get();
```

And if you want to set a condition in to children relationship

```
$parents = Parent::withWhereHas('children', fn($q) => $q->where('status', 1))->get();

// notice i use here foreach looping , because get will return a colletion
foreach ($parents as $parent) {
    // to count the children after this query
    count($parent->children); // should return 36
}
```

And if you want to return both children and the counter of a single Parent

```
$parent = Parent::query()
   ->withCount('children')
   ->with('children')
   ->where('id', 20) // optional , but best to filter which parent
   ->first(); // this will return a single

// to access how many children
$parent->children_count;

// to access each children 
foreach ($parent->children as $child) {
   // do something here
}
```

And if you only want to count all of children, I suggest you use Children.

```
$children_count = Children::count(); // add filter when needed
```

---

**EDIT:**
To grab all children and yet in the same query showing how many children with status active (1), you can adjust your eloquent query into this:

```
// I grab only the first Parent with id 1
$parent = Parent::query()
   ->withWhereHas('children')
   ->withCount(['children' => fn ($q) => $q->where('status', 1)])
   ->where('id', 1)
   ->first();

// this will return all children with any kind of status 
$this->assertTrue( $parent->children->count() === 36 );

// this will return counted children with only status active (1)
$this->assertTrue( $parent->children_count === 6 );
```

**note:** I have test it in my local test area and work perfectly.
The only difference here is using **query()** at the beginning.
And of course extra where() and return only the first Parent.

---

I hope this can help you out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help ! It does the trick !

Comment: good to hear this help you out